# Correct steps to setup Ambari on a centos VM

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am using: **CentOS 7** with **Ambari 2.1.1** to try and setup a single node setup on a VM. I want to do this to install vanilla hadoop etc instead of installing a prepackaged VM with some modified version of hadoop.

I am logged in as root. I have created a ssh key pair. I also ran: 
"cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys" 
"chmod 700 .ssh/" 
"chmod 640 ./ssh/authorized_keys"

I have edited /etc/ssh/sshd_config to: permit empty passwords, allow root login and also to state where the authorized_keys file is.

Without a password I can run "ssh root@localhost" and log in fine.

I have ran "ambari-server setup" successfully and logged in at localhost:8080 with user: admin pass: admin.

In "Install Options" FQDN I typed "localhost.test" and have selected a copy of my private key for the Host Registration Information.

But not matter what I do I am unable to get the components install under the confirmed hosts part and thus can't get any further.

Can someone please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: If I am correct, The host registration got failed right? Can you provide the error information? Check selinux status also. It should be disabled.

Comment: can you paste the errors you are getting and all the steps you followed in seres?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Yusaku on HortonWorks forum for the help.

Ok I ran:

```
hostname -f
```

and got localhost

```
python -c ‘import socket; print socket.getfqdn()’
```

and got localhost.localdomain

By entering `localhost.localdomain` into the FQDN I was able to get the install working.

Comment: To add for other users: You can also check if ambari-agent is also running on the host which is also another reason that host registration will fail.